# Highcharts Tooltip - Getting rid of the marker dot?

Tags: javascript, web, highcharts

I would like to get rid of the small dot in my tooltip display. I am using High-charts. I Can you please help in modifying this feature, here is my code:

```
 Highcharts.getJSON(
  'https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.topo.json',
  topology => {
 
    const chart = Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
      chart: {
        map: topology
      },
 
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
 
      legend: {
         enabled: false,
         align: 'center',
         verticalAlign: 'bottom',
         itemStyle: {
             fontWeight: 'bold',
             fontSize: '20px'
         }
     },
 
      mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        enableDoubleClickZoomTo: true,
        buttonOptions: {
          align: 'right',
          verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
      },
 
      mapView: {
        maxZoom: 30,
        projection: {
          name: 'Orthographic',
          rotation: [60, -30]
        }
      },
 
      colorAxis: {
                         min: 0,
                         max: 100,
                         text: '',
                         stops: [[0, 'darkgrey', ''], [0, '#5ce1e6', '{{question['answer1']}}'], [0.49, '#c9f5f7', ''], [.50, '#aee0a0', ''], [.51, '#fff4c8', ''], [1, '#ffde59', '{{question['answer2']}}']],
                         title: {
                          text: '',
                          },
                     },
 
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
 
      tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        pointFormat: '{point.name} <br> <div style="display: inline-block;" class="square-answer1-globe"></div>{{question["answer1"]}}: {point.value1}% <br> <div style="display: inline-block;" class="square-answer2-globe"></div>{{question["answer2"]}}: {point.value2}%',
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        style: {
        color: 'white'
         },         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
     },

      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          animation: {
            duration: 750
          },
          clip: false

        }
      },
 
      mapline: {
             color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
           },
      series: [{ 
           name: 'Graticule',
           id: 'graticule',
           type: 'mapline',
           data: getGraticule(),
           nullColor: 'lightgrey',
           color: 'lightgrey',
           accessibility: {
          enabled: false
        },
        enableMouseTracking: false
         },
        
      
      {
        data,
        joinBy: 'name',
        name: '',
        states: {
          hover: {
             color: '',
            borderColor: '#000000'
          }
        },
     
        accessibility: {
          exposeAsGroupOnly: true
        }
      }]
    });
```

Here is an image of what is displayed: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlcVI.png)

I want to get rid of the little dot in the top left of the tooltip box. I have been trying everything and it always seems to appear there. I have tried adding in "Marker: false", but maybe I am not inputting it in the correct spot (not sure if this is the correct code).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `formatter` option for the tooltip, something like this, but add your values:

```
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function(tooltip) {
      return `${question1}: <b>${percentage1}</b><br/>`
    }
  },
```

Here is documentation about it: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: To be more specific, `tooltip.pointFormatter` seems to be more relevant in that case https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter but overall `formatter` is a good solution as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That worked for the marker tooltip issue, but now the values "point.name", "point.value1" and "point.value2" are not being read properly. They are just returning as is in string format.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you use double brackets to wrap values?

Comment: I solved the problem. I had to use 'this.' and it worked --> ${this.point.name}

Thanks for the help